# Keeping session alive with ajax in php

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP app where i want to keep session alive irrespective of server setting. I made a ajax call as follows to make a call to server via ajax in a interval...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                var refresh_session = function(){
                    var refresh_interval = 180000;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: 'refresh-session.php',
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(){
                                refresh_session();
                            }
                        });
                    }, refresh_interval);
                }
                refresh_session();
            });
        </script>
```

and in server i have this code...

```
 <?php
  @session_start();
  $_SESSION['last_refreshed_time'] = time();
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i a', $_SESSION['last_refreshed_time']).' - '.session_id();
 ?>
```

i see the ajax call is made on the specified interval and i can see same session ID on every ajax output. But still page gets logged out if i refresh after 30 minutes... Can some one tell me why the session is not being alive on this case even though i made server call in few minutes ?

Comment: You're setting the session in a remote page without refreshing the current page. Without refreshing the current page after setting the session, the session does not exist in the current page. If you have `session_start()` in your existing page, refresh it after setting the session.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for your help. but if i can refresh current page in time interval then no need to put the ajax call to separate page itself. The aim is to keep session alive even though user is inactive for more than 30 minutes. i cant refresh page as some part of application can not get refreshed unless user cancel the action... i also tried with ini setting as like this... ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 180000); ... it does not help too...

Comment: The session will never exist in the current page unless the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If your server session timeout is at 30 mins that means 1800 segs that means 180000 microseconds like you have in your script, but when it get executed the session already expires. You have to refresh the session before it dies. Try changing the value to 1790 segs or 179000 microseconds so you have 10 seconds to execute the ajax and refresh the session.

Update this variable to 179000

```
var refresh_interval = 179000;
```